# Redirect all URL's in host with multiple domains on the same server

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have the following issue.

I'm using a shared server on godaddy. and i have more than one site on the same server.

I need to redirect all urls from one of the sites to another URL within the same site

I found this in several SO answers

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com [OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test.html$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/test.html [R=permanent,L]
```

It's working fine but there's one problem, it is redirecting all of my other sites too.

How can i fix it? i'm kinda stuck here

Edit -

The htaccess file is on the root directory.

Comment: WHERE on your server did you put this .htaccess file? remember that .htaccess is processed in file-system order, so if you put that file ABOVE the directory where all your sites live, then it's going to apply to ALL of those sites.

Comment: Where did you put the .htaccess?

Comment: at first i put the file inside the domain directory, but it was causing me a loop and error on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `[OR]` condition in your 2 `rewritecond` lines which means apply redirection when:

1. host name in request is `mysite.com` **OR**
2. URI is `/test.html`

So if either of those 2 conditions match redirection will happen.

Most likely you meant this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/test\.html|\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com/test.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It worked but now i have an issue, all background images are not loading, because of the redirection.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava its now working great, just added the ".jpg" extension that seems it wasnt working and btw does that "?" sign in "jpeg" it's a typo or it's meant to be?

Comment: Actually `jpe?g` was meant to cover `jpg` and `jpeg` both